# What is the easiest way of intercepting library calls in Windows?

Tags: c, windows

I want to monitor/filter internet traffic. I planned on doing this by intercepting calls to send and receive in the WinSock API. Patching/disassembling are too difficult and time consuming. The dll method is also very time consuming because all I want to patch are 2 calls and I have to reproduce the entire dll. Is there an easy method to produce the redirect dll? Or perhaps an easier method to intercept the calls?

Comment: Calls to an API are not system calls…

Comment: This is always done at the kernel level with a filter driver so you catch all machine traffic, not just process-local traffic.  WinPcap is the standard solution. http://www.winpcap.org/

Comment: @hans, winpcap doesnt give me the option to drop an outbound packet / modify its data

Comment: Sure it does, source code is available.

Answer (score 2):

Disassembling and patching is not easy, that's why there is DLL injection & hooks that can be used for interception. Here is all you need to get started:

- [DLL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection).
- [Three Ways to Inject Your Code into Another Process](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of Winsock there are custom interfaces you might try, for example [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463267.aspx) (Vista+) and  [Layered Service Providers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) (older OS).

Comment: Another ability that I want is to be able to stall the request which these other services dont provide

Answer (score 1):

You can use DLL injection. An exemple use of MS Detours library is given there:

http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-online-poker-bot-7

The author uses Detours to hook the `DrawText` API function.